# What are internal and external packages in android

Tags: decompiling, apk, android, android-applicationinfo

I have been using tools like androgurad, dedexer and apktool to decompile android apk files and have been viewing the statistics. While analysing the packages dependencies in apk files, I noticed that there are **internal and external packages**. Please explain the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually those packages which are not available to developers through the official SDK they are called internal.

Comment: Oh I see, could you please give some examples of such packages? Are ad libs, dev tool, analytic packages considered as external packages?

Comment: How about the main code of the app being developed, is it considered as an external package?